# How to add a download task to my service that is running?

Tags: android, download, android-service

I have a service which does downloading task , when its downloading a file , how can I add another download task to it (another file )? 
Should I recall it : ?
startService(serviceIntent);

My service :

```
public class downloadService extends Service {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Create an array of Asyn task and execute after complete download.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using AsyncTask 
Create Broadcast Receiver in service and whenever you want to download you can pass link using Broadcasting it

Add this in service

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String url= intent.getStringExtra("DownloadUrl");
   // Call downloadmethod from here
 }
}
```

for registering reciver add this code in Service onCreate

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.demo.BroadcastReceiver");

MyReceiver myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
```

and whenever you want to download you can use this code and send broadcast

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
intent.setAction("com.demo.BroadcastReceiver");
intent.putExtra("DownloadUrl", Url);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view,

1) You should organize download queue, that will holds metadata of future files for ex.: URL, file name, folder for saving this file, state of downloading, etc. 
2) You should create class DownloadTask that will working in background thread. As input this class should use one item from Metadata queue.
3) You should create ExecutorService inside your service with single thread pool Executor(on demand you can change pool size for your needs) and execute DownloadTasks.
4) Also you should to know when your download task is finished. In this moment you should pop the HEAD item from metadata queue and run new DownloadTask.